# Where is wg-revert-workgroup in Emacs for Workgroups 2?

Tags: workgroups

I'm a bit confused with Emacs for Workgroups, because I have so many problems with it.

Is wg-revert-workgroup something which is not present in Emacs for Workgroups 2?

Comment: I guess https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2/issues/108 will help.  Sounds like EFWG2 might be fairly different to EFWG1, so maybe if you want the latter you should just use that?  I know nothing about it though.